# Octopus Deploy does not deploy some files present in the package

Tags: asp.net, octopus-deploy

I am developing a .NET web app and I want to deploy it with Octopus Deploy. When I build the app in Release mode all the output files are saved in the `bin\Release` folder as expected. When I deploy the project with Octopus Deploy all the files located in `bin\Release` are copied to `C:\Octopus\Applications\Development\MyService\1.0.0.0_N`. That is fine.

The problem is that today I have added 2 new files to the project. When I build they get saved in `bin\Release` folder as expected, but when I deploy they are not copied to `C:\Octopus\Applications\Development\MyService\1.0.0.0_N` together with the other files. What is that?

Comment: How do you deploy your artifacts _to_ Octopus? OctoPack? Bamboo? Are these new files present in your artifacts?

Comment: I use OctoPack to make packages. I don't know.

Comment: Yes they are present in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It was beacause in C:\Octopus\Packages\MyService there was already an old package named MyService.1.0.0.0. Therefore it didn't even try to download the new updated package. Now I have deleted the old package and inserted the new one and it works. The only thing that still perplexes me is that package replacements ought to occur automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got the "skip already installed packages" option set on your project *and/or* you are not replacing the package version in the library properly...

Check the settings on your Octopus project:

[image: Package re-deployment option]

## Package re-deployment

- Always deploy all packages
- Skip any package step that is already
  installed

*If the skip option is selected and Octopus detects the same package version is already installed on the deployment target, all features of a package step will be skipped. By default, Octopus will always re-deploy every included package.
Disable this project*

## Check the package library

[image: Upload a package]

Pay special attention to the **Replace the version if it exists** checkbox.

https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-repositories/pushing-packages-to-the-built-in-repository

For `Octo.exe` you need to specify the `--replace-existing` switch to mimic this behaviour.

### Caution!

You should be *very* careful replacing versions of things in the library.

If you've changed the code/repository/etc. you have created a **new version**, and as such your version number should *not be the same*.

You can potentially screw up your ability to rollback to a previous version if you have replaced the version that was used.

Comment: Right now I have the "Always deploy all packages" selected.

Comment: @nix86 updated answer to include the library settings